#  Visual Studio 2012 - Can't find System.Transactions assembly in .NET 4.5 framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I'm trying to add a reference to System.Transactions in a C# Visual Studio 2012 project, but System.Transactions isn't available among the framework assemblies, as you can see for yourselves in the below screenshot:
[image: Available framework assemblies]

Does anyone know why System.Transactions would be unavailable to me? How can I make it reappear?

**Edit:**
Fixed the screenshot, thanks Marc!

Comment: I assume it doesn't appear under S...? (sadly the screen stops at P). MSDN suggests it should be there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.current(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MarcGravell Ah oops, my bad. I took another screenshot and forgot to scroll the dialog this time!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There was a Microsoft Connect entry posted for this, which had a comment suggesting that you can browse for it.  The path given is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Transactions.dll

Comment: Cheers, so it turns out to be a Visual Studio issue.

Comment: @cybermonkey   Don't you like it when Microsoft kills links. I removed it and left the suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

install in packages NuGet... Visual Studio: Castle.Services.Transaction