# The type or namespace name 'Transactions' does not exist in the namespace 'System'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2013, transactions

This is in an ASP.Net web application, with Visual Studio 2013. The solution is composed of several projects. I have code in a library project that has `using System.Transactions`, and it's worked well for months.

Today I added the same `using System.Transactions` in code in the web application project, and it fails with the error message below:

```
The type or namespace name 'Transactions' does not exist in the namespace 'System'
```

Here are a few things I've tried:

- Added a reference to `System.Transactions`.
- Verified that the referenced dll file is the same in both projects.
- Changed the framework from 4 to 4.5 and back.
- Verified that all projects are using the same framework version.
- Cleaned and rebuilt the solution.
- Quit Visual Studio, deleted all files in AppData>Local>Temp, rebuilt.
- Restarted the PC.

So, the upshot is that `using System.Transactions` works fine in one project but not another, even though both projects are in the same solution.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** Here's an oddity that's probably not any additional help, but here goes:

- When I build the project, there are no errors. That is, the `using System.Transactions` compiles just fine.
- If I run application, it bombs and the error appears in browser window. The VS code window still shows no errors.
- If I edit the `using System.Transactions` or add code like `var x = System...`, the errors immediately appear in the `using System.Transactions`.

** EDIT:** This question was marked as duplicate. It isn't -- the proposed duplicate solved the question by browsing to the reference. I had already tried that and it didn't help. In my case, I had to use the "copy local" option.

Comment: Are both projects targeting the same platform? It may be a long shot but perhaps an x64 project is trying to reference an x86 assembly or vice versa. Usually when something like that happens to me, the steps you took would have resolved the issue.

Comment: Good question. I checked all projects in the solution, and all targeted "Any CPU." And the references are both to the x86 DLL.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you explicitly change the build output of the web app project to x86? Does the reference appear broken in the project in Visual Studio? Are there any useful error messages in the Output window when building?

Comment: VS can have some pretty major mess-ups sometimes when it comes to referenced libs. I've encountered one myself that took a lot of messing around to fix. Try stupid little things like deleting the reference entirely and adding it back. It's like kicking a gumball machine to get it to dispense, you just need to kick it correctly :-)

Comment: @Colin - I didn't find anything in the Output window (with diagnostic level turned on) that looked different from other references.

Also, I'm editing the original post for a little more info that's really odd.

Comment: @RogueBukkitDev - Yeah, I tried that and other "kicks" as well. No joy still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this [Answer By Mark Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819344/visual-studio-2012-cant-find-system-transactions-assembly-in-net-4-5-framew)

> There is a [Microsoft Connect entry posted](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/736571/vs11-system-transaction-namespace-is-missing#details) for this. There is a comment that suggests that you can browse for it. The path given is:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Transactions.dll

Just Add reference by browsing to this path

if this did not work, Go to References -> System.Transactions and make sure on the properties for this reference that "Copy Local" is set to True.

Comment: I tried that, and still the same problem.

Comment: Can you try this ... Go to References -> System.Transactions and make sure on the properties for this reference that "Copy Local" is set to True.

Comment: That worked, yay! I tested by turning "Copy Local" back off, it failed again; turn it on, and it works. This looks like a good answer, thanks!

One thing that's just a curiosity: In the other library project in this solution, "Copy Local" is off and always has been, and it compiles just fine. Not sure why there's a difference, but I'll just be quiet and be happy.

Answer (score 1):

usually System.Transactions is not part of your references, try to add it in your references by:

right click on your references if you are using Web Application or in your Project if you are using Web Site.
find the System.Transactions in the .NET references.
You should find the System.Transactions in your references.

Comment: Thanks, but that was the first thing I tried (see original post). What worked for me was setting "Copy Local" on the reference to "true." See  comments by Hussein Khalil in his answer.