# Referenced assembly not appearing in using directive

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to access the functionality from `System.IdentityModel.Services`, in particular, `FederatedAuthentication`.

I have added a reference to the assembly, but in code, it does not appear in the using directive list.

My app is ASP.Net Web API C# running on VS2015 Pro.

[image]

Can anyone help me to access it please?

[image]

I've tried with lower case 'i' but to no avail:

[image]

Strangely, if I remove all references to `System.Identity` in the References list, in code, the Using directive for `System.IdentityModel.Tokens` does not present an error.  Is that something to do with the GAC?

Comment: What Framework versions is each project in, I can see v4 for the referenced assembly but what about the consuming project?

Comment: Hi @MattC, in Project Properties > Application > Target Framework it says 4.5

Comment: Changing the project target framework from 4.5 to 4.6 fixed it. If you can provide any information on why that is, I'll gladly accept as an answer :-)

Comment: I don't, it was just a hunch.  Generally, if I can't use a referenced project I've usually got my .Net versions messed up.

In this case the MSDN article states 4.6 and 4.5 so not sure why it didn't work before. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568674(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was fixed by ensuring all projects in the solution had the same target framework (4.6).

Answer (score 0):

Reference added it System.identitymodel.services and not System.IdentityModel.Services

See first char i in identitymodel

Other thing you can check is:
 check the properties of your System.identitymodel.services "Copy Local" should be set to false.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference unfortunately.  identitymodel (lower i) is not listed in Intellisense.

Comment: Other thing you can check is: check the properties of your System.identitymodel.services "Copy Local" should be set to false.

Comment: Yes, copy local is set to False.  I've just updated my question with more information which I hope might lead to an answer

Comment: I followed two links: at one link it was mentioned to  set local copy to false. While at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248051/the-type-or-namespace-name-transactions-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-syste it's mentioned to set it to true. Also it's mentioned to add your reference by browsing to the path. Check the refered link if it helps

Comment: Very helpful.  Although copy local did not affect anything, setting the project target framework from 4.5 to 4.6 fixed it.  If you can provide any information on *why* that is, I'll gladly accept as an answer :-)

Comment: dll which you were referring to, was built using 4.6. If you change target framework to 3.5 or lower you will get similar error for other references as well, because they were built using high version of .net framework